# R studio: Dygraph two axes, a bar chart and line chart

Tags: r, xts, dygraphs

I have the following problem:

I have an XTS file with 2 variables, A and B. I believe there is no standard way of plotting variable A on axis 1 as bars and variable B on axis 2 as a line - other than using custom plotters from here http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html.

```
tempo0 = data.frame(Date=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2017-01-01",format="%Y-%m-
%d"), to =as.Date("2017-01-30",format="%Y-%m-%d"), by = 1), A = runif(30,0,100), B = 1:30)

tempo1 = xts(tempo0[-1],tempo0[,1])

dygraph(tempo1)%>%
dyAxis("y", label = "Depth", valueRange = c(0, 30), independentTicks = TRUE)    %>%
dyAxis("y2", label = "Temp ", valueRange = c(0, 100), independentTicks = TRUE)  %>%
dySeries("A", axis=('y2'))
```

An example of this is: 
https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/e71e0726-1cd3-401a-983a-8be362598600.jpg

An exention of this would be: given variables X1...Xn and Y. X1...Xn as a stacked graph on the first axis and Y as a line chart on the second axis.

Thank you,

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598123/how-do-you-create-a-bar-and-line-plot-with-r-dygraphs/ That should do the trick...