# dygraph bar charts with negative values in R

Tags: javascript, r, r-dygraphs

I have time-series data that I would like to plot in R with `dygraphs` with bars as opposed to lines.  I am using the following `plotter` suggestion from the [dygraphs documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-custom-plotters.html).

```
dyBarChart <- function(dygraph) {
  dyPlotter(dygraph = dygraph,
            name = "BarChart",
            path = system.file("plotters/barchart.js",
                               package = "dygraphs"))
}
```

The problem I am having is representing negative values.
With a line plot, this `dygraph()` works as it should:

```
dygraph(test)
```

[image]

However, when we add the bar chart, nothing is plotted and warnings are returned:

```
dygraph(z)  %>%  dyBarChart() 
There were 14 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()

Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path) : path[1]="": No such file or directory
2: In file.copy(from, to, overwrite = TRUE, recursive = isdir) : too deep nesting
3: In file.copy(from, to, overwrite = TRUE, recursive = isdir) : too deep nesting...
```

Is there a known workaround for plotting negative values in R dygraph barcharts?

Here is the sample data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(c(-6L, 0L, -4L, -1L, 2L, 0L, 18L, -3L, -2L, -1L, -2L, 
1L, -22L, -5L, -1L, 3L, 11L, 2L, -2L, 5L, -3L, -1L, -2L, 0L, 
12L), index = structure(c(1521217200, 1521217800, 1521218400, 
1521219000, 1521219600, 1521220200, 1521220800, 1521221400, 1521222000, 
1521222600, 1521223200, 1521223800, 1521224400, 1521225000, 1521225600, 
1521226200, 1521226800, 1521227400, 1521228000, 1521228600, 1521229200, 
1521229800, 1521230400, 1521231000, 1521231600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), class = "zoo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try the example in the link you provided you will see it does not work. But thanks to: [How do you create a bar and line plot with R dygraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598123/how-do-you-create-a-bar-and-line-plot-with-r-dygraphs)

Here is the right dyBarChart function for your code to work.

```
dyBarChart <- function(dygraph) {
    dyPlotter(
        dygraph = dygraph,
        name = "BarChart",
        path = system.file("examples/plotters/barchart.js",package = "dygraphs")
    )
}

dygraph(test) %>% dyBarChart()
```