# Difficulty reproducing stacked bar graph in R using dygraphs

Tags: r, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

I’ve been using the dygraphs R package to produce some wonderful timeseries plots, but am having great difficulty reproducing the examples located here:
http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-custom-plotters.html

I’m particularly interested in creating a stacked bar chart:
[image: Desired stacked bar chart]

My data is an xts/zoo object and plots nicely using the standard `dygraph` function:
[image: sample plot]

However, I am unsure where the `dyStackedBarGroup` function comes from. It appears these functions must be created, and point to the specific plotters in .js files.

I can see for the first example, how `dyBarChart` is created, but there is no stackedbarchar.js/stackedbargroup.js in my local dygraph installation (however I can see the file in https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/tree/master/inst/plotters).

I’ve attempted to source all the functions and .js files from the github page which do not appear to be made available when loading the dygraphs package locally, but I remain unsuccessful.

Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598123/how-do-you-create-a-bar-and-line-plot-with-r-dygraphs? Although `fdeaths` is not on the chart on that page, the code has the directory structure correct to the .js file that is needed and was easily reproduced.

Comment: I did, but I wanted to make sure how much of an idiot I was being for not being able to follow the RStudio custom plotter guide.

Comment: In any case, thanks for introducing me to `dygraphs` - they're beautiful and I'd never heard of them before!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set `stackedGraph` argument in `dyOptions` to `TRUE`. `dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE)`.

The javascript file for the barchart can be found at "examples/plotters/barchart.js" of the `dygraphs` package directory.

Data:

```
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, ldeaths)
```

Code:

```
# create dygraph plotter
library('dygraphs')
dyBarChart <- function(dygraph) {
  dyPlotter(dygraph = dygraph,
            name = "BarChart",
            path = system.file("examples/plotters/barchart.js", package = "dygraphs"))
}

dygraph(lungDeaths) %>%   # create dygraph of lungDeaths
  dyBarChart() %>%        # create bar chart with the passed dygraph
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE)  # make it as stacked bar chart
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you kindly. Will reward the bounty as soon as it lets me.

Comment: `dygraph(lungDeaths) %>% dyStackedBarChart()` works too